# How to include Vcpkg on CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: c++, windows, macos, cmake, vcpkg

So I have a project which depends on opencv, which is installed with vcpkg. The project is build with cmake.

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19.1)

set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE ~/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake)

project(mylib)

set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

include_directories(~/vcpkg/installed/x64-osx/include)

link_libraries(${OpenCV_LIBS})

set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS TRUE)

add_library(mylib SHARED mylib another_lib)
```

As can be seen, I'm trying to use the same `CMakeLists.txt` to build it on macOS and Windows.

The `link_libraries(${OpenCV_LIBS})` translates nicely between different OSs.

But `include_directories(~/vcpkg/installed/x64-osx/include)` only works on `macOS`, on `Windows` it should refer to `C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include` instead.

Is there any opecv/vcpkg I can use inlace of these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `include_directories(~/vcpkg/installed/x64-osx/include)` looks odd. This should be instead that:

```
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use vcpkg in the manifest mode https://vcpkg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/manifests/

This way you create a JSON file listing all of your dependencies and when invoking `cmake` vcpkg will automatically bootstrap and install all the dependencies.

Comment: Link doesn't work, can you update this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`include_directories` and `link_libraries` is old style `cmake` and should be avoided. `target_link_libraries` should be used instead.

Also using paths specific your our system is not recommended.
`CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` value should be provided when configuring project.

IMO it should go like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19.1)

# this way others can override this value form command line
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE ~/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake CACHE FILEPATH "Path to toolchain")

project(mylib)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS TRUE)

add_library(mylib SHARED mylib another_lib)

# this should resolve problems with include and linking at the same time
# and only yor target will be impacted (and targets linking your target 
# since PUBLIC is used)
target_link_libraries(mylib PUBLIC ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```